# C# Regex Match Number Followed by Closing Parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a number followed by a closing parenthesis: "2)", but not match a number contained within opening and closing parentheses: "(2)".  This regex works, except when the number has more than one digit:

```
string text = "blah blah: 1) blah blah; and 2) blah blah.  (1) Blah blah; and (10) blah blah.";
string pattern = @"[^(]\d{1,}\)";
MatchCollection matches = new Regex(pattern).Matches(text);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}

// output:
// 1) 
// 2)
// 10)  This should not be matched, since it is really (10)
```

How can I modify this regex to match numbers that are followed by a closing parenthesis, but not preceded by an opening parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression ***10)*** is matched as follows:

- ***1*** is `[^(]`
- ***0)*** is `\d{1,}\)`

Try with this one:

```
string pattern = @"[^(\d]\d+\)"
```

To avoid breaking the number.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you want to match an opening parenthesis, number(s) and a closing parenthesis.

```
string pattern = @"[^(]\d+\)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`string pattern =  @"(?<=\s)\d+(?=\))"`

and based on your input, it will match numbers (shown in bold)

blah blah: **1**) blah blah; and **2**) blah blah.  (1) Blah blah; and (10) blah blah.1